# remove all special characters from string to make it a valid email (but keep äöüß)

Tags: php, email, preg-replace

So im trying to remove all whitespaces, new lines, tabs, special chars from a String to make it a viable Email-Adresse, but I cant use `var_filter` with `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` because it would remove ä,ö,ü,ß.

currently workaround, but it looks realy stupid and I'm sure there is a better way to do it!

```php
if(strpos($string, '\'')) {
    $string = str_replace('\'', '', $string);
}
if(strpos($string, '"')) {
     $string = str_replace('""', '', $string);
}
if(strpos($string, '/')) {
   $string = str_replace('/', '', $string);
}
```

I also tried `preg_replace` but I cant find any list on how to format this correctly.

```php
$$string = preg_replace('/\s+/,\',",/', '', $string);
```

Should be able to transform this email:

```php
peters.müller        @      email.  /
com'"
```

into:
`peters.müller@email.com`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found an answer:

this keeps all acents(äöüß), and doesnt remove ". ; @ _" which are used in emails.
Need the semicolon as an seperator for multiple emails in a String.

```php
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9\-.;@_]/u', '', $string);
```